# How to change firebase project on Android studio?

Tags: android, firebase

I have created a project on firebase and **connected my app with android studio firebase assistant**. I **want to change** the project and connect to **another project on firebase**.

I have tried with changing google-service.json but I discovered the project on android studio does not use the json file. I have deleted and put other projects json file but the app still works with previous project details on both scenario. I have also made invalidate cache and restart but got same result. I can not find any file that I can change to make the project use other firebase secret json file or credential. What can I do in this situation? Do I have to create a new android studio project and connect via assistant with it?

in the screenshot shown the firebase assistant connected to a firebase project. How can I change this connection?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It keeps previous google-service.json file information thats why this problem happens.

Solved it by,

1. removing `id 'com.google.gms.google-services` from build.gradle(app),
2. changing firebase dependencies `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'` on build.gradle(project).
3. Clean build.

Done.